# Windows VM creation using a disk snapshot from Azure CLI

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli, snapshot

Is there a way to create a Windows VM from a disk snapshot using Azure CLI? Surprisingly. there are so many great documentation, but I got different error during my attempts like `Use of securityProfile.securityType setting is not supported for attached OS disk.` or `Security type of VM is not compatible with the security type of attached OS Disk.`

Answer (score 0):

### Preparations

You need to download the latest version of the azure-cli client.
The link is here: https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows

### The code

The following code helped me.
Specify the parameters considering your needs!

```cpp
REM The Subscription ID can be seen on any Azure resource in the "Essentials" section.
set subscriptionId=<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>
set resourceGroupName=<YOUR RESOURCE GROUP NAME>

REM Defining some common and disk-related parameters
set diskName=<TYPE A DISK NAME>
set zoneId=1
set snapshotName=<TYPE YOUR SNAPSHOT NAME>
set osType=windows
set secType=TrustedLaunch
set diskVmGeneration=V2
set diskArchitecture=x64
set diskSize=128
set diskStorageType=StandardSSD_LRS

REM Defining some VM-related parameters
set virtualMachineName=<TYPE A VM NAME>
set vmSize=Standard_D2s_v3
set licenseType=Windows_Server
set vnetName=<TYPE A VNET NAME>
set publicIpAddressAllocation=static
set publicIpAddressSku=Standard
set isSecureBootEnabled=true
set isVtpmEnabled=true


REM Logging in
az login

REM Selecting the subscription
az account set --subscription %subscriptionId%

REM Getting the snapshot Id - This step is commented out because the snapshot name can be added to the disk creation script
REM for /f %i in ('az snapshot show --name %snapshotName% --resource-group %resourceGroupName% --query [id] -o tsv') do set snapshotId=%i

REM Creating a new managed disk
az disk create --resource-group %resourceGroupName% ^
               --name %diskName% ^
               --zone %zoneId% ^
               --source %snapshotName% ^
               --os-type %osType% ^
               --hyper-v-generation %diskVmGeneration% ^
               --architecture %diskArchitecture% ^
               --size-gb %diskSize% ^
               --sku %diskStorageType%

REM Creating vnet
az network vnet create --name %vnetName% --resource-group %resourceGroupName%

REM Creating a new VM using created managed disk
az vm create --resource-group %resourceGroupName% ^
             --name %virtualMachineName% ^
             --zone %zoneId% ^
             --security-type %secType% ^
             --attach-os-disk %diskName% ^
             --os-type %osType% ^
             --size %vmSize% ^
             --license-type %licenseType% ^
             --vnet-name %vnetName% ^
             --public-ip-address-allocation %publicIpAddressAllocation% ^
             --public-ip-sku %publicIpAddressSku% ^
             --enable-secure-boot %isSecureBootEnabled% ^
             --enable-vtpm %isVtpmEnabled%
```

### Useful info

Disk creation parameters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/disk?view=azure-cli-latest#az-disk-create

Vnet creation parameters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-vnet-create

VM creation parameters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create